# JS target multiple classes and repeat infinitly

Tags: javascript, dom

The JS below works exactly like it should, my JS knowledge is 0%. Only thing is i need the code below to target multiple divs but same id or different id's does not matter. It also needs to be infinite. so every 50 seconds it needs to repeat. The goal of the js below is to reset CSS3 animations i have running. Project files can be found here: www.dreamsynk.com/img/slider.

```
// retrieve the element
element = document.getElementById("ani");

setTimeout(function() {
// -> removing the class
element.classList.remove("one");

// -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
// without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be    retriggered.
element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

// -> and re-adding the class
element.classList.add("one");
}, (50*1000)); //40 seconds
```

UPDATES:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="inner">
    <div id="ani" class="one"></div>
    <div id="ani" class="two"></div>
    <div id="ani" class="three"></div>  
    <div id="ani" class="four"></div>
    <div id="ani" class="five"></div>
    <div id="ani" class="six"></div>
</div>
</div>


// retrieve an array-like object with elements
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("ani");

setTimeout(function() {
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
var element = elements[i];
element.classList.remove("one two three four five six");
element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
element.classList.add("one two three four five six");
}
}, (50*1000)); //50 seconds
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `document.getElementsByClassName` if you want to have an array of elements. `document.getElementById` normally only gives you the first element of that ID.

The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.

You can also use `document.getElementsByName()`,
`document.getElementsByTagName()`,
`document.getElementsByTagNameNS()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` of course.

---

The elements you get from `document.getElementsByClassName` is known as a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Methods), which is just an array. So if you want to add elements into the collection you can use `array.push`.

```
var array = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
var element = document.getElementById("ani");
array.push(element);
setTimeout(function() {
    var i = array.length; 
    while(i--) {
       array[i].classList.remove("one");
       array[i].offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
       array[i].classList.add("one");
    }
}, (99999));
```

---

Updates:

1. `.classList.remove()` can only do 1 class at a time. The same goes
   to `.classList.add()`.

   What you can do is to create a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) for `DOMTokenList`
   like this:

   ```
   DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany = function(classes) {
       var array = classes.split(' ');
       for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
         this.add(array[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

   and remove/add the classes this way:

   ```
   element.classList.addMany("one two three four five six");
   ```
2. By the way for [`.querySelectorAll(selector)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), you are not using
   a proper CSS selector.

   You can read more about the syntax of CSS selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors).

   And as I have mentioned before, **you can't have duplicate ids.**

   Ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: I have 0 js knowledge i dont know what to do with that DOMTokenList :/  anyway to show me finished code please <3, would greatly appreciate it

Comment: @user2810762 Sure. Here they are: http://0.0ar.ch/sample1.html, http://0.0ar.ch/sample2.html. Just save the page and/or view the source code or open it with your favorite text editor. You can email me at archy@0ar.ch if you have any more question. I will try my best to help you as long as I'm free from work and feel like doing some non-commercial coding. (I am normally quite busy though.)

Comment: I can pay you aswell if i am really having issues. I will paypal you and then when it shows yourside you can do the work. Thanks alot for all your help m8!

Comment: Sent you a mail because this is becoming a conversation. Was one really small part thats not there which is the infinite part of the js , so activating every 50 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to get elements with any css path and then every 50 seconds iterate between them and do the same steps you did for your single element.

Code fixed for your use case:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="ani" id="one"></div>
    <div class="ani" id="two"></div>
    <div class="ani" id="three"></div>  
    <div class="ani" id="four"></div>
    <div class="ani" id="five"></div>
    <div class="ani" id="six"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var container = document.querySelector('slider');
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(container.querySelectorAll(".ani"));

setTimeout(function() {
  elements.forEach(function(el) { el.classList.remove('ani'); });
  container.offsetWidth = container.offsetWidth;
  elements.forEach(function(el) { el.classList.add('ani'); });
}, (50*1000)); //50 seconds
```

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. I also made your code do a single reflow for all elements instead of one for each element and used a functional way of iterating over the elements array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// retrieve the elements
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        // -> removing the class
        elements[i].classList.remove("one");

        // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
        // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be    retriggered.
        elements[i].offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

        // -> and re-adding the class
        elements[i].classList.add("one");
    }
}, (50*1000)); //50 seconds
```